# HTML select option from a Google Spreadsheet range

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a code that really work, everything I tried doesn't work. May someone help me?

```
Sidebar.gs

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Update project')
      .addItem('Open', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
```

The sidebar appears properly, but there is no data in the combo. What did I missed?

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Project updater')
      .setWidth(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

Index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <p>Create sub-folders </p>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script> // SpreadSheet
          var activSpSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          // Feuille répertoires créés
          var foldersSh = activSpSh.getActiveSheet();
          var lastRow = foldersSh.getLastRow();
          var myRange = foldersSh.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow); 
          var data    = myRange.getValues(); 
    </script>
    <div>
      <select>
        <script> for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { </script>
        <option><script>= data[i].getvalue(); </script></option>
        <script> } </script>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `createTemplateFromFile()` method instead of the `createHtmlOutputFromFile()` method.

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Project updater')
      .setWidth(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

The code that you now have in a `<script>` tag, needs to be in a script (server side) file with a `return data;` statement.

### code.gs

```
function myFunction() {
  var activSpSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Feuille répertoires créés
  var foldersSh = activSpSh.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = foldersSh.getLastRow();
  var myRange = foldersSh.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();

  var optionsHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length;i+=1) {
    optionsHTML = '<option>' + data[i] + '</option>';
  };

  return optionsHTML;
}
```

And then you need to use a printing scriptlet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <p>Create sub-folders </p>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <select>
       <?!= myFunction(); ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not able to create the relationship between the 2 functions and the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script methods run on the server side so they can't be called directly in a HTML file. Instead they should be called by use on of the several methods available. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication for further details.